# How to create a Custom Routed Event ? WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic-data-display

I followed [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752288.aspx) but I couldn't apply what I learned to my project.

I have a [`LineGraph`](https://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Stable/v0.3.1/src/DynamicDataDisplay/Charts/LineGraph.cs) object [(Dynamic Data Display)](https://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/) and I want to create an event that is raised when the thickness of the LineGraph is equal to 0.

How am I supposed to write it following this tutorial ?

Comment: What is the exact problem you are having, why couldn't you apply the tutorial ?

Comment: I don't work D3 but it seems the `LineGraph` object doesn't have thickness property ?

Comment: Can you post some code so that we can see what the problem is?

Comment: It's late, but for some other seeker: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms752288(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, I usually avoid creating events, preferring  instead to create `delegate`s. If there is some particular reason that you specifically need an event, then please ignore this answer. The reasons that I prefer to use `delegate`s are that you don't need to create additional `EventArgs` classes and I can also set my own parameter types.

First, let's create a delegate:

```
public delegate void TypeOfDelegate(YourDataType dataInstance);
```

Now a getter and setter:

```
public TypeOfDelegate DelegateProperty { get; set; }
```

Now let's create a method that matches the in and out parameters of the `delegate`:

```
public void CanBeCalledAnything(YourDataType dataInstance)
{
    // do something with the dataInstance parameter
}
```

Now we can set this method as one (of many) handlers for this `delegate`:

```
DelegateProperty += CanBeCalledAnything;
```

Finally, let's call our `delegate`... this is equivalent to raising the event:

```
if (DelegateProperty != null) DelegateProperty(dataInstanceOfTypeYourDataType);
```

Note the important check for `null`. So that's it! If you want more or less parameters, just add or remove them from the `delegate` declaration and the handling method... simple.

Answer (score 13):

Here is how I would do it with a RoutedEvent:

1. Create a class that derives from `LineGraph`, let's say `CustomLineGraph`:

   ```
   public class CustomLineGraph : LineGraph {
   }
   ```
2. Create our routed event like this:

   ```
   public class CustomLineGraph : LineGraph {

       public static readonly RoutedEvent ThicknessEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("Thickness", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler, typeof(CustomLineGraph));

       // .NET event wrapper
       public event RoutedEventHandler Thickness
       {
           add { AddHandler(CustomLineGraph.ThicknessEvent, value); } 
           remove { RemoveHandler(CustomLineGraph.ThicknessEvent, value); }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Now we override the `StrokeThickness` property so we can raise our custom routed event when the value of that property is `0`.

   ```
   public class CustomLineGraph : LineGraph {

       public static readonly RoutedEvent ThicknessEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("Thickness", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler, typeof(CustomLineGraph));

       // .NET event wrapper
       public event RoutedEventHandler Thickness
       {
           add { AddHandler(CustomLineGraph.ThicknessEvent, value); } 
           remove { RemoveHandler(CustomLineGraph.ThicknessEvent, value); }
       }

       public override double StrokeThickness {
           get { return base.StrokeThickness; }
           set
           {
               base.StrokeThickness = value;
               if (value == 0)
                   RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(CustomLineGraph.ThicknessEvent, this));
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. We are done !